# Confluent CLI - Register schema using confluent command

Tags: confluent-platform, confluent-schema-registry

I am running confluent kafka in docker and is unable to use rest api calls due to firewall restrictions on the port. I am trying to use "docker run confluent". As per this [link](https://docs.confluent.io/confluent-cli/current/command-reference/schema-registry/schema/confluent_schema-registry_schema_create.html#confluent-schema-registry-schema-create), I should be able to use "confluent schema-registry" command for this, but when I tried running "confluent" command from the terminal (After installing confluent-cli), I am not able to see and option for "schema-registry"

```
Usage:
  confluent [command]

Available Commands:
  cloud-signup    Sign up for Confluent Cloud.
  completion      Print shell completion code.
  configuration   Configure the Confluent CLI.
  context         Manage CLI configuration contexts.
  help            Help about any command
  kafka           Manage Apache Kafka.
  local           Manage a local Confluent Platform development environment.
  login           Log in to Confluent Cloud or Confluent Platform.
  logout          Log out of Confluent Cloud or Confluent Platform.
  plugin          Manage Confluent plugins.
  prompt          Add Confluent CLI context to your terminal prompt.
  secret          Manage secrets for Confluent Platform.
  shell           Start an interactive shell.
  update          Update the Confluent CLI.
  version         Show version of the Confluent CLI.
```

All the installations are latest in docker. What could be the problem or is there another way to publish an avro schema (avsc) which I have locally in a file  into the schema registry instance running on docker?

confluent version v3.32.1
The docs are as of version 3.3

Comment: How do you know the version is correct ? Compare `confluent version` to the version mentioned in the docs

Comment: Good point. Edited in the question.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by `docker run confluent`? The docker repo is `confluentinc` and so what image are you actually running?

Answer (score 0):

> is there another way to publish an avro schema (avsc) which I have locally in a file into the schema registry instance running on docker

Yes. You could use an HTTP client like `curl` to register against the Registry API. This is all the `confluent` CLI would do.

https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/schema-registry/develop/api.html#post--subjects-(string-%20subject)-versions

Alternatively, schemas are automatically registered when you start producing data with AvroSerializer.